# How do I use variables in a separate script in Unity3D?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Title explains it all, I want to know how to access variables from another script. I've searched online, but found nothing that's worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make a `class`, instantiate an `object` of the class and access propterties.
Or you could use `static` variables.
Or even beter, lets say you have a `GameManager.cs` script attached to an empty object called GameManager. And you want to access its variables form the `LevelManager.cs` script. You do this inside the `LevelManager.cs`

```
public GameManager gameManager;
```

Then you can drag and drop your GameManager empty object to this public field, and everytime you want to access a variable you type `gamemanager.yourVariableHere`
Or, if you dont want to drag and drop:
in the start method...

```
void Start()
{
 gameManager = GameObject.Find("GameManager");
 //this way it finds your object automatically
}
```

Hope it helped, good luck.

Comment: Thanks for helping me even when my post had a score of -3. It worked, so thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First you need to make your variables public. Then get the GameObject, get the Componend and access your variable.

```
var variable = GameObject.Find("name").GetComponent<ScriptClass>().yourVariable;
```

Answer (score 0):

To add to the previous answer, if your class is a pure c# class and doesnt inherit from monbehaviour then must create an instance of class. If you want global access to certain variables you should look into static variables or implement a singleton  pattern