# How to access enums and variables from another C# script Unity3d

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, enums

In Unity, I have

```
public enum inven {Food,Scissors,Nothing};
public inven held;
```

How can I access the `enum` and, more importantly, the information contained in the `held` variable, from another script.
I tried the Singleton Method:

```
public class Singleton : MonoBehaviour {

    public static Singleton access;
    public enum inven {Nothing, Scissors, Food};
    public inven held;

    void Awake () {
    access = (access==null) ? this : access;
    }
}
```

to make global variables, accessed by

```
Singleton.inven.food //or
Singleton.access.held //respectively
```

However, that returned "Null reference exception: Object reference not set to an instance of an object."
I also tried using this:

```
public class Accessor : MonoBehaviour {
    void Start() {
        GameObject HeldItem = GameObject.Find("Story"); //where story is the Gameobject containing the script of the enum and variable
        TextController textcontroller = Story.GetComponent<Textcontroller>(); //Where TextController is the sript containing the enum and variable
    }
}
```

accessed by `TextController.held` etc, returned that it needed an object reference. What is the proper way of doing this?

Comment: I asnwered a similar question here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33113980/how-do-i-use-variables-in-a-separate-script-in-unity3d/33123618#33123618

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I do my singletons. In my case, it's called `SharedData`.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Booter : MonoBehaviour
{
    void Start ()
    {
        Application.targetFrameRate = 30;
        GameObject obj = GameObject.Find("Globals");
        if(obj == null)
        {
            obj = new GameObject("Globals");
            GameObject.DontDestroyOnLoad(obj);
            SharedData sharedData = obj.AddComponent<SharedData>();
            sharedData.Initialize();
        }
    }
}
```

This script is attached to an object in the first scene that loads, and it is set in the script execution order to go first. It creates a GameObject to attach the SharedData component to, then tells the engine not to delete that GameObject when new levels are loaded.

Then to access it, I do this:

```
public class Interface : MonoBehaviour
{
    private SharedData m_sharedData;

    public void Initialize()
    {
        GameObject globalObj = GameObject.Find("Globals");
        m_sharedData = globalObj.GetComponent<SharedData>();

        m_sharedData.LoadData(); // This is where I use something on the singleton.
    }
}
```